# How can I resolve yii2 Not Found #404 problem?

Tags: controller, yii2, runtime-error, http-status-code-404, gii

I have created new controller in the project with gii but I am getting Not Found (#404) error when I try to access it.please help me why i get this error?
here is the controller:

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers\phone;

use Yii;
use common\models\phone\UssdCode;
use backend\models\phone\UssdCodeSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * UssdCodeController implements the CRUD actions for UssdCode model.
 */
class UssdCodeController extends Controller
{

    public function getViewPath()
    {
//        return \Yii::getAlias('@backend/views/phone/ussdcode');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all UssdCode models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new UssdCodeSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single UssdCode model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new UssdCode model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new UssdCode();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->UssdCodeId]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing UssdCode model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->UssdCodeId]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing UssdCode model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the UssdCode model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return UssdCode the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = UssdCode::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

and here is the model:

```
<?php

namespace common\models\phone;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "tbl_ussd_code".
 *
 * @property int $UssdCodeId
 * @property int $CategoryIdRef
 * @property int $SubCategoryIdRef
 * @property string $CodeDescription
 * @property string $UssdCode
 * @property int $Status
 */
class UssdCode extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'tbl_ussd_code';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['CategoryIdRef', 'SubCategoryIdRef', 'CodeDescription', 'UssdCode'], 'required'],
            [['CategoryIdRef', 'SubCategoryIdRef', 'Status'], 'integer'],
            
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'UssdCodeId' => 'Ussd Code ID',
            
        ];
    }
}
```

and here is the index:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel \backend\models\phone\UssdCodeSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Ussd Codes';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="ussd-code-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Ussd Code', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'UssdCodeId',
            'CategoryIdRef',
            'SubCategoryIdRef',
            'CodeDescription',
            'UssdCode',
            //'Status',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>


</div>
```

Access url is:
http://localhost/test/backend/ussdcode/index

why I get Not Found (#404)??

Comment: Try `http://localhost/test/backend/ussd-code/index`

Comment: No, this did not work and it gives the same error.

Comment: Try to create a different vhost for backend and frontend. Or try to modify it using shared hosting structure: https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/topic-shared-hosting

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with the **naming** of the `controllers` and ....

**For example:**

```
ussdcode becomes app\controllers\UssdcodeController;
ussd-code becomes app\controllers\UssdCodeController;
```

*This means that the view folder is named as ussd-code and the URl address is called as ussd-code.

[Controller Class Naming](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers#controller-class-naming)

> Controller class names can be derived from controller IDs according to
> the following procedure:
>
> - Turn the first letter in each word separated by hyphens into upper case. Note that if the controller ID contains slashes, this rule only
>   applies to the part after the last slash in the ID.
> - Remove hyphens and replace any forward slashes with backward slashes.
> - Append the suffix Controller.
> - Prepend the controller namespace.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be issue related to namespaces. In the controller UssdCodeController you are user following namespace statement:

```
namespace backend\controllers\phone;
```

For controllers, it should not have sub-folders. Move your controller files directly under `backend\controllers` folder, and change the namespace like:

```
namespace backend\controllers;
```

And you are good to go.